# CamelContext.getRoutes() return size =0 until context started

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am doing CamelContext.addRoutes() in a loop and at the end if I check CamelContext.getRoutes().size() it return 0 until context is started.

Start context only if any route is added.

I want to know if it is expected behaviour or is it a but. 
I think its a defect. Please let me know this is as expectected or if I need to post this question in any camel specific forum.

Answer (score 2):

Try `camelContext.getRouteDefintions()` as they are the route models. So they ought to be added asap, when you use addRoutes.

Comment: Small addition: `CamelContext.getRouteDefinitions()` is deprecated and `ModelCamelContext.getRouteDefinitions()` should be used instead.

Comment: @Peter since getRouteDefinations() is depricated and getRoutes dosnt reaturn count until start then what to use to check how many routes added to camelContext.

Comment: @sandeep Just use `ModelCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext()` for initializing the context.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. The `routes` are filled up after starting the context in `DefaultRouteContext.commit`:

```
DefaultRouteContext.commit() line: 206  
RouteDefinition.addRoutes(CamelContext, Collection, FromDefinition) line: 916    
RouteDefinition.addRoutes(ModelCamelContext, Collection) line: 177   
DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(RouteDefinition) line: 770   
DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(Collection) line: 1914   
DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel() line: 1670   
DefaultCamelContext.doStart() line: 1544    
DefaultCamelContext(ServiceSupport).start() line: 61    
DefaultCamelContext.start() line: 1512
```